# Using Leaflet Timedimension module offline

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i'm trying to use Leaflet offline to show a map with a moving marker, using Geojson data. I was able to use Leaflet offline, downloading all dependencies and running a local webserver: i can load the map using local tiles and show the polyline.
Now i want to make the marker move and i need to use Timedimension plugin. To do that, i downloaded the files listes here:

https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/tree/master/src
https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/tree/master/dist

I put the files in the same Leaflet folder and i edit the path in the index.html as i did for the other Leaflet files. The only thing i edited is the CSS file `leaflet.timedimension.control.css` to remove online dependencies for Glyphicons Halflings:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
src: url(./glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot);
src: url(./glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'), url(./glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff) format('woff'), url(./glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf) format('truetype'), url(./glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular) format('svg');}
```

Unfortunately when i run the page, i can't see the slider bar, and the console reports no error messages. What am i doing wrong? I understand Leaflet has not been designed for offline applications, but it's very frustrating having everything working but the very last piece Timedimension. Maybe there are other online dependencies?

The script runs correctly and then stops at the last command, which relates to the Timedimension usage:

```
var geoJSONTDLayer = L.timeDimension.layer.geoJson(geoJSONLayer, {
            updateTimeDimension: true,
            duration: 'PT2M',
            updateTimeDimensionMode: 'replace',
            addlastPoint: true
 }).addTo(myMap);
```

Note: all .js and .css files referred to Leaflet and Timedimension are stored in a folder named "offline". They are correctly found since the map and paths are correctly showed.